# Change/Replace keyboard character on keypress while writing new post

Tags: javascript, customization, characters, input

Before opening this thread in here, I was searching all the day today a way to change/replace 2 keyboard keys when writing a new post on wordpress. What I need is, when an editor/admin press `[` on the keyboard wile writing, to replace instantly to `ë`; and when press `]` to replace with `ç`. As I searched online, the `[` unicode is `91` and `] = 93` (somewhere else, in other cheatsheet, it appears to be 92). What I have tried is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(event){
$(document).delegate("input, textarea", "keyup", function(event){
    if(event.which === 91) {
        var cleanedValue = $(this).val().replace(/\[/g,"ë");
        $(this).val(cleanedValue);
    }
});
});
```

...by trying to make use of this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EutHr/) but it seems to not work in wordpress. (yes, I have included the js on the admin, and verified that it is there)
So, that's the big question and would appreciate any help from you.
Thank you in advance!